# Node.js + Express: file structure and communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a login application but I am having trouble communicating the credentials of the form (`email` and `password`) to my existing `.js` files, where it performs some logic and retrieves some info.

On my `login` page I have a `form` with a `POST` method. Then, I have a `main.js` that performs the login:

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
  returnSessionToken: function(success, error) {
    var email = email_X;
    var pwd =  password_Y;

   [...]
function(error, response, body) {
   var login = JSON.parse(body);
   success(login.sessionToken)
}
```

And then I have a `index.js` where I retrieve some info of the logged user:

**index.js**

```
var authToken = require("./main");

authToken.returnSessionToken((result) => {
   'my_website_token': result,
   [...]
}
```

In my `express` project, I have these two files in a `js` folder. What I am trying to do is getting the email and password of the `form` of the login page and pass it to my `main.js` file (`email_X` and `password_Y`) and then call `index.js`. I know how to get the `req.body.email` and `req.body.password` in the `routes` folder, but stil can't figure out how to make these files communicate.

I have also tried to edit the `app.js` file into:

**app.js**

```
var login = require('./js/main');
```

and then,

```
app.use('/myaccount', login);
```

But no success.
Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, here's a working example. Thank you Ryan Villanueva for the help!

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
  returnSessionToken: function(email, pwd, success, fail) {

    var email = email;
    var pwd =  pwd;
    success(token)
    [...]
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = {
  returnUserData: function(authToken, success) {
  [...]
  'my_website_token': authToken,
}
```

**app.js**

```
var myaccount = require('./routes/myaccount');
app.use('/myaccount', myaccount);
```

**routes/myaccount.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var login = require('../js/main')

router.post('/', function(req, res) {

  var email = req.body.email
  var password = req.body.password
  login.returnSessionToken(email, password, (token) => {
      console.log("return token: ", token)
      var logged = require('../js/index')
      logged.returnUserData(token, (myData) => {
        res.render('myaccount', { myData: myData });
      })

    },
  (fail) => {console.log(fail)})

})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused by the details and what looks like some missing steps, but it looks like the problem may be caused by the way you're setting up and referencing your main.js module.

`app.use('/myaccount', login)` will send your main.js module two objects, generally referenced as req and res. req contains information about the http request. I believe the data from a form HTTP post is sent in req.body.

See example below:

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var login = require('./login');
var app = express(); 

app.use('/login', login); // mount the sub app
```

**login.js**

```
var express = require('express'); 
var login = express(); 

login.post('/', function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.body); // should print your form data

  // do your login logic here

  res.status(200).end(); // Sends http response back
});

module.exports = login;
```

Comment: you meant `login.js` or `main.js`?

Comment: `throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));`

`TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object`

Comment: You've referenced `var login = require('./js/main')`, so it looks like your login variable is sending to your main.js file.

Is the error being thrown in your code or mine? (Edited code for a small typo for unreferenced 'express')

Comment: I'm guessing the error is being thrown in your code. That's probably because you're passing app.use('/myaccount', login) your module.exports, which is just an object containing your `returnSessionToken` function. Instead, pass it a express.post('/') or equivalent, which is the middleware function that creates an API route for you to post to.